# How to check all possible combinations of numbers in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's assume that I have a long list of list where every sublist is a combination of two different numbers.
Example:

`[ [1,6], [7,3], [11,2], [6,3], [8,1], [4,11] ]`

I also have an input of three numbers: A, B and C (e.g. 6, 1, 3).

Now I want to check if A number has pairs with both B and С numbers. For the example above the answer is yes, because A number (6) has one pair with B (1) - [1,6] and also has one pair with С (3) - [6,3].

Since all these numbers can be combined with each other in any way I'm using a dirty bruteforce solution now:

```
if ([A, B] in list and [A, C] in list) or
([A, B] in list and [C, A] in list) or 
([B, A] in list and [A, C] in list) or 
([B, A] in list and [C, A] in list) or...
```

There must be a better approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about filtering the components in a list with list comprehension?

```py
>>> target_list = [ [1,6], [7,3], [11,2], [6,3], [8,1], [4,11] ]
>>> A, B, C = 6, 1, 3
>>> filtered_list = [l for l in target_list if A in l and (B in l or C in l)]
>>> filtered_list
[[1, 6], [6, 3]]
>>> if len(filtered_list) == 2:
...     do_something()
```